# Edit search results web part master page in a team site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

i am able to edit the search results master pages for a **search center** (by adding a new html-file, the js-file is auto-generated).

How can i do the same thing in a **team site** for the search results web part? Looking at the master pages catalog, i can see only javascript-files there? Am i assumed to edit these js-files? Or where are the html-files located?

So I just want to show custom layout for specific content types in an search results web part in a team site!

A bit confused here!
thanks a lot for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must activate Publishing feature for site collection or web - after that you will have ability to create and edit display templates for search results.